# how to render nested json object with key using ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to search solution but did't get it.I also used nested ng repeat and different methods using ng repeat, Items values always appearing in string form.

I want to display like this,

```
   _id: 59889d877560a92480a4b354
   firstName: ayaz
   lastName: khatri
   items: 
         _id:item3,
         _name:My Item #4
         _price:999.99
         _quantity:1

   totalItems: 1
   totalPrice: 999.99
```

Here Controller

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.userInfo = {
    "_id" : ObjectId("59885d800560a92480a4b354"),
    "firstName" : "ayaz",
    "lastName" : "khatri",
    "items" : [ 
       {
             "_id" : "item3",
             "_name" : "My Item #4",
             "_price" : 999.99,
             "_quantity" : 1
       }
              ],
    "totalItems" : 1,
    "totalPrice" : 999.99
    }

  });
```

Here ng view

```
  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl" class="container" style="padding-top:30px">
   <ul ng-repeat="user in userInfo">
     <li ng-repeat="(x,y) in user">

      {{x}}:{{y}}

     </li>

   </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `ng-repeat="user in userInfo"` can't work because `userInfo` is one object, not an array (list) of objects.

Comment: if you will remove ObjectId with parenthesis then this will work properly.  – Jeremy Thille

Comment: Oh yeah right, of course, `ObjectId` is a MongoDB thing, it's undefined in Angular. Doesn't your console say `ObjectId is undefined`?

Comment: I'm using mongodb, it's just a sample to understand

Comment: I know you're using Mongo. It doesn't change the fact that `ObjectId` doesn't belong to Angular and is undefined here. _Check your console._ It's probably yelling errors.

Comment: check now http://plnkr.co/edit/6jTrwMKdLDcH5T3ZFiS7?p=preview

Comment: See? Works better, doesn't it?

Comment: @JeremyThille I guess Question owner want to parse nested object keys and values without double quotes and scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I forked your plunkr example it works [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0z5lUZB6yuAixbbLXlH8?p=preview)

You can determine whether your nested value is object or not by creating custom angular `is_object` method and implement like following.

**// javascript**

```
$scope.is_object = function (something) {
    return typeof (something) == 'object' ? true : false;
};
```

**// html (list solution)**

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in userInfo">
  <li ng-repeat="(x,y) in user">
    {{x}} :
    <span ng-if="is_object(y) == false"> {{ y }} </span>
    <ul ng-if="is_object(y)">
      <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in y">
          <br>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="(k2,v2) in v">
               {{k2}} : {{ v2 }}
            </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**//html (table solution)**

```
<table ng-repeat="user in userInfo" border="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="(x,y) in user">
    <td>
        {{x}} :</td>
        <td>
        <span ng-if="is_object(y) == false"> {{ y }} </span>
        <ul  ng-if="is_object(y)" style="list-style:none; margin-left:-60px">
          <li class="border-right: 1px solid" ng-repeat="(k,v) in y" style="float:left;border-right: 1px solid" >
              <br>
              <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="(k2,v2) in v">
                   {{k2}} : {{ v2 }}
                </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If items have multiple objects then how will it work?

Comment: bro do u have solution ?

Comment: @NomanKt  I have updated my answer, now it works as you wish, you can use this for multiple objects.

Comment: bro can you use table instead of list?

Comment: @NomanKt you can change html tags according to your need for example you can use <tr>, <td> tags with ng-repeat

Comment: @NomanKt I have updated the answer and plunkr example, now it also works with table tag

Comment: Thanks bro, can you convert it in horizontal row?

Comment: @NomanKt I have updated answer again, you can use style="float:left;border-right: 1px solid" to get horizontal line for list group. But I didnt understand why you didnt accept the answer although it is worked for your question

Comment: dont you want to parse li group horizontally as updated plunkr example works? Also this answer solves your question

Comment: @NomanKt I guess this http://plnkr.co/edit/gX1McwdxKERxkULIQj17?p=preview link works like as you wish